# Changing "via" and "mailed-by" contact form 7 WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

When using contact form 7 all messages go to SPAM.

This is due to the fact that the settings inside "via" and "mailed-by" are using my own hosting servers and not my domain name.

I already tested this on my own so I know this is the issue.

The problem is how to change "via" and "mailed-by" inside contact form 7.

See this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rajfp8

I want to change the "via" and "mailed-by" from displaying my hosting server to the name of my domain.

Instead of this "via cloud.hostgator.com" and "mailed-by: cloud.hostgator.com"

I want this "via mydomain.com" and "mailed-by: mydomain.com"

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: You'll have to use SMTP instead of wp_mail

Comment: I end up eliminating that contact form 7 plugin and use plain and simple HTML form with a simple PHP script, that solve the issue in my case

Comment: @Howard E What do you mean by your comment? How could I do that in **"contact form 7 plugin"**?